# Multi-monster fights in Munchkin Quest

Tags: munchkin-quest

I've read the manual but don't fully get multi-monster fights. It says you can't chose to fight one, and flee from others. But do you sum up all the monster points and try to beat that in one single combat, or do you fight one monster at a time?

Comment: And, wait, you are fighting one monster and other ones are noble and don't take part in the duel? :-)

Answer (score 9):

The monsters combine their strengths: you don't fight them one at a time.

This [was confirmed](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?p=922026) by the "Munchkin Czar" at the Steve Jackson Games Forums, and who would dare to argue with a Munchkin Czar?  (You may find extra clarification of how multi-monster fighting works by reading through the thread, if you're still at all confused.)

Comment: You sum their levels, bonuses, *and* dice, correct?

Comment: @Peeja, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed here, however:

- Monsters combine their strengths for a combat score.
- Buffs and weaknesses apply to one monster at a time.
- You can only interfere with up to one monster at a time, unless you have a card that says otherwise.

  - Example: You can only make one monster humongous. However, a thief's backstab ability applies to the sum of all combat strength.
- You must run away from each monster if you lose separately. Damage is taken from each monster, and "bad stuff" can happen to you multiple times.